# fixed effects model with country - industry - time variables

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I am researching the effect of country and industry factors (ex. GDP, import, export) on wage difference. I gathered data at industry level for 75 countries, 19 industries, for 5 years and trying to analyze using a fixed effects model.

I would like to know how to identify the dataset as a panel data for sector-by-country and time using R. I learned that the following code will be used in case of Stata. Is there a similar code for R?

```
egen country_industry = group(country industry)
xtset country_industry time
```

I tried using the following code in R, but it did not work:

```
library(plm)
panel8 =pdata.frame(sampledata7_industry, index=c("id","industry","year"))
```

The error code is as follows:

```
> library(plm)
> panel8 =pdata.frame(sampledata7_industry, index=c("id","industry","year"))
Warning message:
In pdata.frame(sampledata7_industry, index = c("id", "industry",  :
  duplicate couples (id-time) in resulting pdata.frame
 to find out which, use, e.g., table(index(your_pdataframe), useNA = "ifany")
```

The first few rows of my data is as follows:
[sampledata7_industry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHuAb.png)

Should I re-number the ID to combine the country and industry? One idea is as follows:

[Re-numbering of sampledata7_industry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSmmv.png)

Comment: Please provide data. At leas few rows, so we can reproduce it. You can use function `dput()` to post a minimal dataset.

Comment: @Bloxx Thank you for your comment. I added the first few rows of my dataset "sampledata7_industry" as above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that, in Stata, your grouping variable is country-industry, while in R, you're trying to group on two variables, country and industry. According to the documentation for pdata.frame:

> The index argument indicates the dimensions of the panel. It can be:
>
> • a vector of two character strings which contains the names of the individual and of the time indexes

So it should work if you combine 'id' and 'industry' into a single variable like you did in Stata.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried using the following code to combine "id" and "industry", but I do not know what to do after these codes. I would appreciate it if you could tell me the code to move forward.

library(dplyr)
panel = group_by(sampledata7_industry, id, industry)

Comment: Or should I re-number the ID to combine the country and industry? I posted the first few rows of this updated dataset as "Re-numbering of sampledata7_industry" above.